# Javascript format Date without timezone

Tags: javascript

In this code it actually display the server date using minus the date difference and add back the difference. 
The result will show: Tue Jan 20 09:18:06 UTC+0800 2015

But i just want to show -> Tue Jan 20 09:18:06 2015   which is without the timezone, is there anyway to format the Date object in myTimer() function? I checked in java doc there is no constructor which down to time without timezone.

```
var d = new Date(
<%=sdate.get(Calendar.YEAR)%>,
<%=sdate.get(Calendar.MONTH)%>,
<%=sdate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)%>,
<%=sdate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)%>,
<%=sdate.get(Calendar.MINUTE)%>,
<%=sdate.get(Calendar.SECOND)%>
);

var delta = d.getTime() - Date.now() ;
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d  = new Date(Date.now() + delta);
    var t = d.toString();   
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}
```

Comment: [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) is a heaven send when it comes to working with dates in javascript.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation, but too sad i cant use external lib for this.

Comment: `datestring.split('UTC')` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [toLocaleTimeString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString):

```
var options = { weekday: 'short', year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric', hour12: false };
console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString("en-US", options));
// Tue, Jan 20, 2015, 08:28:41
```

It's not identical to your required output, but it's close. It's also a bit dependent on your browser version, but you *did* say you couldn't use an external library, so these are the pitfalls of that decision.

Word of warning about chopping up `toString` - it's not the same on all implementations/locales. Mine, for example, outputs `Tue Jan 20 2015 08:29:54 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)`

Comment: hi, i tried ur solution, but why it only display time only(without date)? even with those options.

Comment: Strange. Which browser?

Comment: IE version 11. Following is my code,i did as same as urs,


    function myTimer() {
 var options = { weekday: 'short', year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric', hour12: false };
 var d  = new Date(Date.now() + delta).toLocaleTimeString("en-US", options);
 //var t = d.toString(); 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
}

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is to replace the unwanted string with empty one:

```
t = t.replace('UTC+0800 '+d.getFullYear(),'');
```